# Silverlight Component Performances

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, .net-4.0

I mentioned some Performance-Problems with the Silverlight Components.
I've got a `StackPanel` (for example) and I want to add 6000 Buttons to it.

When I startup the screen loads a minimum of 5 to 6 Seconds. After all The Buttons are rendered and I move my Mouse over some of the Buttons the Highlighting is very slowly.
But first of all here is the example code:

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, Width = 1000, Height = 1000};

for (int i = 0; i < 6000; i++)
{
     panel.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Button" });
}

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(panel); //LayoutRoot is a Grid
```

If I split the `StackPanel` in several panels and add the buttons to it, then the hovering performance is better then before. Here is the code:

```
StackPanel root = new StackPanel {Orientation = Orientation.Vertical};

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     StackPanel row = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal};
     for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++)
     {
          row.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Button"});
     }
     root.Children.Add(row);
}

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(root);
```

What is the reason for this hovering performance problem?

Some more Information about my Developer Machine:

Silverlight 4, Visual Studio 2010, .NET vs. 4, all Updates are installed

Comment: Do you really need to add 6000 buttons to a `StackPanel`? A different UI might be a better solution here.

Comment: Its a performance test of how much controls silverlight can handle.

Comment: Silverlight 5 has been released and allegedly has performance improvements. Might want to try that as well.

Answer (score 2):

If these 6000 Buttons are not visible at the same time but hidden by a scrollbar you might want to try and use the [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) it prevents the generation of invisible child controls.

Comment: That Solution is just a work around for me, why silverlight can´t paint 6000 Buttons in one stackpanel?

Comment: What would be an acceptable minimum for you?

Comment: I can`t say a acceptable minimum amount of controls. The question is, why Silverlight can`t handle so much controls. If i place 10.000 Buttons in a HTML Page, the hover effect of each button works fine, in silverlight not. Even if i place a combobox, which include several comboboxitems, and 6000 Buttons, the hover effect of the comboboxitems is poor.

Comment: To be honest, I think this all as useful as a car that can go 500 mph in a traffic jam. I am glad Microsoft decided that they had to put their effort in other issues. I really don't care that a browser can do this because I will never need it.